# MVC routing problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a webgrid and in that webgrid I have a hyperlink. When user clicks on the hyperlink, I want them to go to a details page.
For this, I have a controller 'Details' method which takes an argument. But for some reason the argument is always null. 
Where am I doing wrong??
Here is the webgrid;

```
grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Advert", "Details", new { id = item.Title }))
```

and here is the controller;

```
public ActionResult Details(string title)
    {
        var ad = (from p in dc.Advert
                  where p.Title == title
                  select new AdvertIndexViewModel()
                  {
                      Title = p.Title,
                      UserName = p.UserProfile.Name

                  }).First();
        return View(ad);
    }
```

in the above method, the 'title' is always null...!! Will be great if someone can help me to find the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the name of the route param matches the action method param. In this case, `title`...

```
Html.ActionLink("Advert", "Details", new { title = item.Title })
```